# how to check tomcat/mysql from outter server using java

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I need to know if tomcat/mysql is running in another server. But I don't know how to.
if you know the way of checking processes status which is running outter(?) servers, I mean not local server. please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the `http://127.0.0.1:8080`(which is used to know the status on localhost), use `http://<ip-address-of-the-desired-server>:8080`.